# Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=location_update flg=0x10 (has extras) } with JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to parse a JSONObject inside a BroadcastReceiver ,and my app keeps crushing showing me this error ***Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=location_update flg=0x10 (has extras) }*** on line 122 (**JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(json_string);**)
 Though , when I remove all the parsing part everything goes well.
Here is the necessary code :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(broadcastReceiver == null){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                try {
                    getJSON();
                    JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(json_string);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");

                    int i=0 ;
                    Double latitude, longitude;
                    while (i<jsonArray.length()){
                        JSONObject jo= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        latitude = jo.getDouble("latitude");
                        longitude = jo.getDouble("longitude");
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.taxi))
                                .title("taxi"));
                        i++;
                } }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                lngg= intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude",-1);
                latt= intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude",-1);

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latt,lngg))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.locationpeople1))
                        .title("I am here "));
            }
        };
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_update"));

}

public void getJSON(){
new BackgroundTask().execute();

}


class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
    String JSON_STRING;
    String json_url ;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        json_url="http://frequentative-hicko.000webhostapp.com/A.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();
            while( (JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ){

             stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();




        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       // TextView textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       // textView.setText(result); //JSON Format
        json_string=result;
    }
}
public  void parseJSON(View view){
  if(json_string == null){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Aucun taxi n'est disponible pour l'instant",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your getJSON call creates a new task, which will run on another thread. So probably `new JSONObject(json_string);` has `json_string = null`. Can you put an if checking this right above your `jsonObject = new ... ` ?

Comment: ok ,I'll try it now

Comment: No, actually it showed me an error .

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: No problem I'll post it

Comment: Sorry , it just too long I didn't know which part I should post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know when you send your broadcast, but here's the problem: when you call your `getJSON` you're telling android to run an instance of your `BackgroundTask` in another thread. So he executes your

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(json_string); // and all the rest
```

before your `getJSON()` finishes. Please try to move all your logic that is after `getJSON()` to your `onPostExecute()`

Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   // This is called when you finish your background task
   // so here is the right place to parse your json response and add yout markers :)
    json_string=result;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(json_string);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");

        int i=0 ;
        Double latitude, longitude;
        while (i<jsonArray.length()){
            JSONObject jo= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            latitude = jo.getDouble("latitude");
            longitude = jo.getDouble("longitude");
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.taxi))
                    .title("taxi"));
            i++;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And in your `onReceive` something like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    getJSON();
    lngg= intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude",-1);
    latt= intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude",-1);

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latt,lngg))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.locationpeople1))
            .title("I am here "));
}
```

Comment: Well ,I send my broadcast from a GPS_Service periodically (every 5 seconds ) , can you please explain more about what I should do !

Comment: I edited my answer with a possible solution, but what you need to understand is that your `getJSON` is asynchronous, so right after you call it, you won't have a valid `json_string` because your task is being executed in the background.

Comment: I did what you've said sir, the app doesn't crush anymore but still it doesn't do what it should (no markers on themap )

Comment: Edited again, Your marker placing logic was correct, only your JSON parsing that should be done inside `onPostExecute`. We're almost there!

Comment: Thanks ,I'll try it

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand, what is the same?

Comment: I mean it still doesn't show the other markers on the map

Comment: Ahh ok, that's another problem I guess, but now your code does not crash and your json parsing is working, right?

Comment: The app doesn't crush ,but when it comes to parsing only this part is workig :   TextView textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView.setText(result); 
            json_string=result;

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: I'm really sorry , but what do you mean !

Comment: You said that your new code now runs until `json_string=result;`, then nothing happens. Open your logcat (alt + 6 in android studio) and you'll see the logs of your device. It should show an exception log, probably a JsonParseException

Comment: I have found these three :  org.json.JSONException: No value for success  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)   at org.json.JSONObject.getBoolean(JSONObject.java:376)

Comment: This means that your json parsing is incorrect, can you print your `json_string`?

Comment: Here it is json_string={"response":{"success":true,"0":{"longitude":"0.00000000","latitude":"0.00000000"},"1":{"longitude":"1.33426070","latitude":"36.15379560"},"2":{"longitude":"5.55550000","latitude":"6.66600000"}}}

Comment: I don't know why "success" shows true but when I tried to print it it said No value for success

Comment: Thanks sir ,I'v solved the problem ,well as you said I moved it all to onPosteExecute than I removed $response["success"] = false; and $response["success"] = true;from the php file

Comment: Glad I helped :). Could you please mark the answer as correct in this case?

Comment: Yes of course ;)  it solved  the error that i wrote in the title.